# how to check if a certain linked list in an array of linked lists is empty

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list

using this data structure: (an array of doubly linked lists)

```
list<string> hashTable [HASH_TABLE_SIZE];
```

I would like to check if a certain linked list is empty using:

```
Hash HashTable;

if(Hash[hf(word)].empty() == true)
{do this}
```

these are the compile errors I get:

```
$ make -f makefile.txt
g++ -g -D HASH_TABLE_SIZE=10 -c hash.cpp
hash.cpp: In member function `void Hash::processFile(std::string)':
hash.cpp:19: error: expected primary-expression before '[' token
makefile.txt:6: recipe for target `hash.o' failed
make: *** [hash.o] Error 1
```

Comment: I don't get it, hashTable is just an array of lists. Where are you hashing? Why not just check if ( hashTable[index].empty() ) {...}

Comment: What are `Hash` and `hf` and what do they have to do with the question?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to explain that the hash function is the hf(word) [which takes the word and turns it into an integer to be indexed] hash is an object of HashTable (which was defined in a .h file)

Comment: I suppose the question I am asking would be; How can I check if the first element of a linked list  is empty in an array of linked lists.

Comment: Then change the title of the question (and the body too) to actually ask this instead of something else.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have compile error. Please, show the 19th line of your hash.cpp file.
Second:

```
Hash[hf(word)].empty() == true
```

is a bad comparison, you can use just

```
 if ( Hash[hf(word)].empty() )
```

And third: list is a dynamic structure, so, I think, better to use array of pointer to list:

```
list<string> * hashTable[HASH_TABLE_SIZE]
```